# Why do i get the error " duplicate key value violates unique constraint "" DETAIL: Key (id_application)=(PR-1005576039) already exists

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

my models.py

```
def document_id():
    random_numbers = random.randint(1000000000, 1009999999)
    doc_id = "PR-" + str(random_numbers)
    return doc_id

class Document(models.Model):
    id_application = models.CharField(default=document_id(), unique=True, editable=False)
    applicant_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    to_whom = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    through_whom = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Pending')
    is_private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    stage = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=STAGES, default='Departmental Review')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

the problem happens every two times i create a document application, for some reasons it is using the last document application id.
I am using a postgresql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```py
id_application = models.CharField(default=document_id(), unique=True, editable=False)
```

Although it might seem intuitive that `document_id()` is called every time you create a new instance of `Document`, this is not true. This is evaluated only once and later the randomly generated value will be the same. So, in case you didn't provide the value for `id_application` when instantiating your model, you will get a duplicated value error when creating a second instance.

To avoid this, you need to provide the default in the `__init__` of the model instead and remove the `default` kwarg from the field definition for clarity.

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.id_application is None:
        self.id_application = document_id()
```

Or, you can also pass the function to the default and it will get called when creating each object. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#default).

```py
# Note that there are no parenthesis
id_application = models.CharField(default=document_id, unique=True, editable=False)
```

Comment: @vinkomlaic i used the second solution and it worked ... thanks so much